# jQTouch - Does it support image maps?

Tags: jquery, jqtouch, imagemap

I'm working to create a jQTouch prototype and would like to use Image Maps, example:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to be working in JQTOUCH - Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the target="_webapp" attribute, and it should work...

So:

```
<map name="planetmap">
  <area target="_webapp" shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
  <area target="_webapp" shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
  <area target="_webapp" shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```